# Can I benefit from a patent application when approaching potential clients?

Tags: patent-applications, india

Can I deal with any company with my patent application number without waiting 3-4 years?

How much time does it take to get an application number after I file for a patent? I'm specifically curious about this timing for the Indian patent office.

Answer (score 1):

Generally an applicant starts marketing his product immediately after the patent application is filed. An application number is given at the time of filing itself on the same day. As per jurisdiction, you are supposed to file the patent application in Delhi patent office.